# SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/" ON <VirtualHost *:443>

Tags: php, apache, configuration, virtualhost

I have a server under apache2 with multiple php versions.
I can use the proxy for  but not for 
I put

```
<FilesMatch \ .php $>
    # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</ FilesMatch>
```

Why does not it work on the 443?

My example:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin email@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </FilesMatch>
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

My VirtualHost *:80 (Which works)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to check your use of spaces as they differ. The FilesMatch is a regex and should be in quotes.

Comment: Do you have an example?
I did put some quotes

Comment: The match should be `<FilesMatch "\.php$">`, you should end with `</FilesMatch>` (you have a space in your first one)

Comment: I just tried but same problem, which is weird that on the configuration in <VirtualHost *: 80> it works

Comment: Can you post exactly your :80? Strictly speaking you don't need the quotes: but you have different issues / spaces etc so you really want to make sure you have copied correctly/exactly and putting in quotes removes ambiguity.

Comment: Yes i have add my virtualhost 80

Comment: That's more helpful! Have you installed mod_ssl? Do html files work on 443?

Comment: Yes the mod_ssl is installed, I see in the apache logs that the site failed to launch a php function being given that it is launched in php 7 and that the function works under php5.6
Thanks for your help anyways

Comment: I found
Because I had several files that deal with virtualhost that's why.
I had a file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf that take care of some virtualhost 443
Thank you very much for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found
Because I had several files that deal with virtualhost that's why.
I had a file **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf** that take care of some virtualhost 443
Thank you very much for the support